# ExtJS 5 Split bar/ button shows background color on panel

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I have a a panel that has two child panels. I am trying to use a `collapseMode: 'mini'` on the top panel. The functionality seems to work, but the background color seems to be showing with the collapse button. This was never a problem when I was on ExtJS 4, but the upgrade to 5 seems to have messed something up.

How can I go about not having the background color show up on the panel?

```
initComponent: function() {
    var me = this;

    Ext.applyIf(me, {
        items: [ {
            xtype: 'myApp-PnlOne',
            region: 'north',
            header: false,
            split: true,
            collapsible: true,
            collapseMode: 'mini',
            border: false,
            bodyCls: 'viewPanelBody'
        },{
            xtype: 'myApp-PnlOne',
            region: 'center',
            header: false,
            layout: 'fit'
        }]
    });

    me.callParent(arguments);
},
```

What is looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think I had this same problem, in my case it was assigning the class "x-autocontainer-innerCt". I fixed it with a custom css class for the element.  If you give the panel an id you can then add css code for "#-innerCt.x-autocontainer-innerCt".  Example:

```
...
items: [ {
            id: 'top-panel',
            xtype: 'myApp-PnlOne',
            region: 'north',
            header: false,
            split: true,
            collapsible: true,
            collapseMode: 'mini',
            border: false,
            bodyCls: 'viewPanelBody'
        }...
```

css code:

```
#top-panel-innerCt.x-autocontainer-innerCt
{
  background-color: #FFFFFF;/*specify the background color you want here or use transparent*/
}
```